# Getting class of variable

Tags: php, class, reflection

How can I figure out in what class a reference to a variable was initiated (and currently exists)?

#### Example:

```
<?php
    class MyClass {
        public $array = array(
            "this",
            "is",
            "an",
            "array"
        );
    }
    
    $class = new MyClass();
    $arrayReference = &$class->array;
    GetClassForVariable($arrayReference); //Should return "MyClass"
?>
```

My best bet is some kind of [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php), but I haven't found any functions that seem suitable for this.

#### Edit:

A better suited example for what I want is the following:

```
<?php
    class API_Module {
        public $module;
        public $name;
        private $methods = array();
        public function __construct($module, $name) {   
            $this->module = $module;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->methods["login"] = new API_Method($this, "login", "Login");
        }
        public function GetMethod($method) {
            return $this->methods[$method];
        }
        public function GetURL() {
            return $this->module; //Should return "session"
        }
    }
    class API_Method {
        public $method;
        public $name;
        private $parentReference;
        private $variables = array();
        public function __construct(&$parentReference, $method, $name) {
            $this->parentReference = $parentReference;
            $this->method = $method;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->variables["myvar"] = new API_Variable($this, "myvar");
        }
        public function GetURL() {
            return $this->GetParentURL() . "/" . $this->method; //Should return "session/login"
        }
        public function GetVariable($variableName) {
            return $this->variables[$variableName];
        }
        private function GetParentURL() {
            // Need to reference the class parent here
            return $this->parentReference->GetURL();
        }
    }
    class API_Variable {
        public $name;
        private $parentReference;
        public function __construct(&$parentReference, $name) {
            $this->parentReference = $parentReference;
            $this->name = $name;
        }
        public function GetURL() {
            return $this->GetParentURL() . "/" . $this->name; //Should return "session/login/myvar"
        }
        private function GetParentURL() {
            // Need to reference the class parent here
            return $this->parentReference->GetURL();
        }
    }
    
    $sessionModule = new API_Module("session", "Session");
    var_dump($sessionModule->GetMethod("login")->GetVariable("myvar")->GetURL()); //Should return "session/login/myvar"
?>
```

Now, this works fine, but I'd love to be able to do this *without* using `$parentReference` in every single subvariable. It might not be possible, but I'd love to know whether it is or not.

Comment: What's `$arrayReference = &$array;` supposed to do? Typo?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yep, it was a typo.

Comment: I'm not certainly sure if this is possible. However I think that you are trying to achieve something what looks like a bad practise/pattern. Could you explain why you need that? What it should be used for?

Comment: @GRoNGoR I'm writing a REST documentation for our framework and I'd love for it to be able to document itself by studying the class - this will not be used in runtime per-se, but rather just to create the documentation HTML files. `PHPDoc` is not suitable, as it also needs to figure out the REST commands itself.

Comment: i would assume that the array is generated in the memory somewhere else than the class. This would mean that the variable is not bound to the class. Just like in any other language (take java for example). You can eliminate the instance and still have a reference to the array.

Comment: I've updated my OP to show the realistic example from the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example:

```
$class = new MyClass();
$arrayReference = &$class->array;
GetClassForVariable($arrayReference); //Should return "MyClass"
```

to find out to which variable originally the alias `$arrayReference` refers to is not possible in PHP. There is no function available resolving the aliases.

Additionally `$class->array` is just a variable on it's own. So you would also need to find out based on a *value* in which class it was defined. That is not possible as well, similar to that PHP does not offer anything to resolve a variable alias, it also does not offer anything to learn about the definition of a variable.

So in short PHP does not have a `ReflectionVariable` class available ;) I wonder if it is even possible.

Comment: From a technical standpoint (in any language), it should be possible as `$class->array` is linked to `$class` somewhere in the memory, and if `$class->array` would know to access the `$array` variable inside of the `$class` class, then the compiler should be able to backtrace memory as well.

Comment: Yes technically I can imagine this is possible. As well for the variable aliasing. Internally the ZVAL container keeps track of that as well otherwise it won't work. Maybe it's worth to create a feature request for such a `ReflectionVariable`? One should make up it's mind about the interface first though.

Answer (score 0):

The get_class() function should work:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

I agree with GRoNGoR that you shouldn't need to get the parent class of a property of an instantiated object. You could instead just get the name of the class before accessing the property. For example:

```
$class = new MyClass();
$parent_class = get_class($class); // returns "MyClass"
$arrayReference = &$class->array;
```

Not sure why you'd need the parent class of the property when you have the object instance and can easily get the parent class from there.